# Can you help me to understand this aproximation?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I'm trying to undestand how a book derives somes physical constants, but I'm struggling with this aproximation: 
it goes from $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(1 - i \tan(x))}}$ to $(1 + i\dfrac{\tan(x)}{2})$, where $i$ is the imaginary unit. It is also mentioned that $\tan(x)$ is close to $0$ so it can aproximated in this way. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the limit development of $(1+x)^c$, where $c=-{1\over 2}$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Comment: Indeed. Many thanks!